# Microsoft Cluster or Oracle Fail Safe error

Tags: oracle, cluster, oracle10g, windows-cluster

Trying to get Oracle Database 10g to work on Microsoft cluster (using Oracle Fail Safe, not RAC). Everything installed, but when trying to verify group or add database to group I get following error:

FS-10220: Network name MSK00-NST01-1 maps to IP address 10.1.11.74 in the cluster resource but maps to IP address 10.1.1.74 on the system

MSK00-NST01-1 is cluster name, 10.1.11.74 is first node IP, 10.1.1.74 is second node IP. Oracle documentation says "The cluster and the system must have the same IP address mapping for a network name. Check that either the network name server or the local host file has the same IP address mapping as the cluster."

Where is the error - in Oracle configuration or in cluster configuration? What are possible ways to correct it? Thanks a lot for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

you added a 1 by mistake ( 10.1.1.74 versus 10.1.11.74). Check again in the cluster admin, on the properties of the ip address

Comment: Sorry, Windows administrator says that there is no error, it's just IPs of different cluster nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Bug 7606294 "Unable To Add Database To Fail Safe Group 3.4.1" DocId: 799024.1

To solve this problem, use the latest version of Oracle Fail Safe. And install patches for Oracle Fail Safe, downloaded from Oracle Support (Metalink).